# How to add input in the middle of a string?

Tags: python

I'm very new to programming, only started learning python ~4 days ago and I'm having trouble figuring out how to print a user input as a string, in between other strings on the same line. Being so new to programming, I feel like the answer is staring me right in the face but I don't have the tools or the knowledge to figure it out lol.

**what I'm trying to do is:**

```
Wow (PlayerName) that's cool
```

**so far what I have is:**

```py
name = input("Name? ")
   
print("Wow") (print(name)) (print("that's cool"))
```

python came back with an error saying object 'NoneType' is not callable, so instead i tried to write it as a function and call that instead:

```
name = input("Name? ")

def name_call():
    print(name)

print("Wow") (name_call()) (print("that's cool"))
```

same issue, I tried various similar things, but at this point I'm just throwing darts

I'm not 100% sure **why** neither of these worked, but I do know that it **probably** has something to do with me writing it incorrectly. I could just print the name on a new line, but I want to try and put them all on the same line if possible.

Comment: `print(...)` returns none ... so `print(...) (anything)` is an error since None is not callable ... the term to google is "python string interpolation"

Answer (score 4):

you can try this code:

```
# Python3 code to demonstrate working of
# Add Phrase in middle of String
# Using split() + slicing + join()
 
# initializing string
test_str = 'Wow that\'s cool!'
 
# printing original string
print("The original string is : " + str(test_str))
 
# initializing mid string
mid_str = (input('Please input name = '))
 
# splitting string to list
temp = test_str.split()
mid_pos = len(temp) // 3
 
# joining and construction using single line
res = ' '.join(temp[:mid_pos] + [mid_str] + temp[mid_pos:])
 
# printing result
print("Formulated String : " + str(res))
```

The result will be like this:

```
The original string is : Wow that's cool!
Please input name = Alice
Formulated String : Wow Alice that's cool!
```

you can input any name to the program.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, I think you're looking for string interpolation. As of Python 3.6 we have f-strings.

```
name = input("Name? ")
print(f"Wow {name} that's cool")
```

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation

Answer (score 0):

Your print's need to be on new lines.

```
name = input("Name? ")

print("Wow")
print(name)
print("that's cool")
```

Python thinks you are trying to call the result of the print function (which returns None) as a function of its own.

```
            |
            V you are accidentally calling the return value here
print("Wow")(print(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val = 'name'
print(f"Wow {val} that's cool.")
```

Btw, if you want `name_call()` to play a role, the following code also works

```
def name_call(): 
    return ('name')

print(f"Wow {name_call()} that's cool.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `format` method to insert `name` into the string's placeholder `{}`:

```
print("Wow {} that's cool".format(str(name)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = str(input('Name: '))
print('user entered {} as their name'.format(x))
```